# Extracting data from big vs little endian

Tags: c++, endianness

Suppose I have a function that should be able to extract any integer type (`char`, `int`, `long`, etc) from any other integer type because some data outputting device likes to pack small data into bigger data types (ie 4 `chars` in a `uint32_t`). I write a function that

1. Takes an array of data
2. Takes a reference to a vector
3. Takes a bool indicating endianess

Does this snippet of the function make sense? I am losing confidence the more I think about it

```
if(data_type_size == SIZE_OF_UINT32){
    uint32_t d = 0;
    if(vector_type_size == SIZE_OF_CHAR){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
            d = data[i];
            if(big_endian){
                v.push_back((d & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
                v.push_back((d & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                v.push_back((d & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                v.push_back((d & 0x000000FF));
            }
            // little endian
            else {
                v.push_back((d & 0x000000FF));
                v.push_back((d & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                v.push_back((d & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                v.push_back((d & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given a `uint32_t` array

```
data[0] = 0x0A0B0C0D;
data[1] = 0x0E0F1011;
```

The above code outputs

```
0xa,0xb,0xc,0xd,0xe,0xf,0x10,0x11
0xd,0xc,0xb,0xa,0x11,0x10,0xf,0xe
```

Which is what I expect. I suppose where I started to get paranoid is thinking about.. well.. is `4F` actually `F4` in little endianess? But I don't think so, because this is byte stuff, not nibble (?) stuff.

Comment: "*is `4F` actually `F4` in little endianess?*" - **no**. "*But I don't think so, because this is byte stuff, not nibble (?) stuff*" - correct. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Another avenue is simply to covert everything to *Network Byte Order* (big endian) and extract your information and covert to *Host Byte Order* when done. See [make 3 byteorder](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/byteorder.3.html). The way you are doing it is perfectly fine as well -- I mention only as another alternative.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but that would be more costly, no? These operations will happen 1000s of times per second.

Comment: Yes, I only mention it because it is a standard way of dealing with differences in endianness. Otherwise, it's up to you to determine the endianness with a byte check of the integer `1` or however you like to do it. It leaves all the endianess handling up to established code.